# spectrum of a convolution operator is connected

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $k \in L^1(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{C})$ and define a linear operator $T$ acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{C})$ by
$$ Tf(x) := [k \ast f] (x) \ldotp$$
Linearity is obvious, while the fact that $T$ is well-defined and continuous is a result of Young's inequality. I'm supposed to show that the spectrum of $T$ is connected but I don't really know how to start - the definition of being connected seems to me to be fairly distant from any properties of spectrum I've seen. For a moment I was hoping that perhaps it's convex, but I don't really think it's true, so any hints on how to approach the problem are most welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at the Fourier transform of $Tf$?

Comment: nope, actually we didn't cover the relationship between the Fourier transform and the spectrum, but I'll look it up if it might help, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: By taking the Fourier transform, you convert this into a multiplication operator. And what you're multiplying by is a continuous, bounded function because the Fourier transform of an $L^{1}$ function is continuous and bounded. The multiplication operator is easier to study, especially its spectrum.